# How to add Roboto font to AMP 4 Email

Tags: amp-html, amp-email

When I add this, I get an error from `The AMP Validator`:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700|Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
    The tag 'link' is disallowed.
```

How should I add fonts from Google Fonts inside an `amp4email`.

Comment: See this [feature request](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/21907).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AMP for Email doesn't currently support custom fonts.

[#21907](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/21907) is the tracking issue for this feature request.

Answer (score 1):

Google fonts include to AMP4MAIL by default. You need just change font-family property in your element. For example for body tag change "Lato" to "Roboto" and it works: `body { font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;}`