# Amp for Email and Google Fonts Validation Error

Tags: amp-html, amp-email

According to AMP documentation, the link tag is allowed for fonts: 
https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/style_and_layout/custom_fonts/?format=websites

However when I embed a Google Fonts link tag in the head:

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

I get a validation error:
The Tag 'link' is not allowed.

Any insights? Thank you for your time and thoughts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Roboto font to AMP 4 Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56006022/how-to-add-roboto-font-to-amp-4-email)

Answer (score 0):

[The docs say custom fonts are allowed in AMP email](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/style_and_layout/custom_fonts/?format=email), yet the validator screams.

I suggest filing a bug issue at the [official AMP project on GitHub](https://github.com/ampproject)

NOTE:  few email clients support custom fonts, so I'd just skip that step if I were you.

Comment: Interesting, that page is *not* part of the email docs (it's not linked to on the left when "email" is selected as format), I'm not sure why it can be opened at all. I filed https://github.com/ampproject/amp.dev/issues/2553 for this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [AMP for Email Supported CSS](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/email-spec/amp-email-css/?format=email#custom-fonts-(@font-face)), which is part of the spec, neither external stylesheets (`<link href="..." rel="stylesheet">`) nor custom fonts (via `@font-face`) are currently supported in AMP for Email.

There's a feature request for adding support for custom fonts: [#21907](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/21907)